# Ngx-tinymce Uncaught TypeError: _this.onChange is not a function

Tags: angular, tinymce

I'm using `ngx-tinymce 7.0.0` from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-tinymce). In installation instructions it uses two-way data binding. It works fine with `[(ngModel)]='html'`. But when I remove `[(ngModel)]`, following error appears in console, when I write something in editor :

```
Uncaught TypeError: _this.onChange is not a function
    at Aw.<anonymous> (ngx-tinymce.js:168)
    at kg.c.fire (tinymce.min.js:2)
    at Aw.fire (tinymce.min.js:2)
    at Hg (tinymce.min.js:2)
    at Object.t (tinymce.min.js:2)
    at C (tinymce.min.js:2)
    at HTMLBodyElement.d (tinymce.min.js:2)
```

Do I've to use `[(ngModel)]`? Because two-way data binding is not considered as good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution for this. If you're not using `[(ngModel)]`, you've to use `[formControl]` present in `ReactiveFormsModule`.

Answer (score 0):

I think tinymce is only worked with two way binding, so its mandate to use ng-model